# Firestore Rules deny every request for chat-app with nested collections. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am currently building a chat-app, and I'm facing an issue with Firebase Rules. I want to restrict users from seeing conversations they are not a part of. However, when I try to implement the rules, it seems that access gets denied even when checking for the existence of a conversation. How can I properly configure Firebase Rules to allow users to see only the conversations they are a part of, and not all the conversations in the database?

[image: This is the structure of the firestore.]

[image: This is how the participants of a conversation are stored.]

This is the ruleset, I was trying to implement solely for the conversations.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // Allow users to read and write their own participant documents
    match /conversation/{conversationId}/participants/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    // Allow users to read and write messages in a conversation they are a participant of
    match /conversation/{conversationId}/messages/{messageId} {
      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/conversation/$(conversationId)/participants/$(request.auth.uid));
    }

    // Allow users to read and write their own conversation documents
    match /conversation/{conversationId} {
      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/conversation/$(conversationId)/participants/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  }
}
```

The access gets denied already at the "very top level", which is this part right here:

```js
// Allow users to read and write their own conversation documents
    match /conversation/{conversationId} {
      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/conversation/$(conversationId)/participants/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
```

I assume, that it has something to do with the way, these nested conversations are working, but I am clueless what I have to change. I tried reading about this in the google firebase docs, but I couldn't find anything regarding this.
If you have any ideas, how to fix this, please let me know. Thank you!

I already tried getting this to work with multiple "rule sets". It always fails at the exists()-function.

I also tried this, but it doesn't seem to work either:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isUserInParticipants(conversationId) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conversations/$(conversationId)/participants/$(request.auth.uid)).data != null;
    }

    match /conversations/{conversationId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && isUserInParticipants(conversationId);

      match /messages/{messageId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && isUserInParticipants(conversationId);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the query I am using in Vue.js:

```
init() {
      const storeAuth = useStoreAuth();
      conversationCollectionRef = collection(db, 'conversation')
      conversationCollectionQuery = query(conversationCollectionRef) 
      this.getConversations()
    },
    async getConversations() {
      this.coversationsLoaded = false
      getConversationSnapshot = onSnapshot(conversationCollectionQuery, (snapshot) => {
        console.log('getConversations')
        console.log(snapshot)
        this.conversations = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.getMessagesOfConversation(doc.id)
          const conversation = {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }
          this.conversations.push(conversation)
        })
      })
      this.coversationsLoaded = true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the query that you're running that is triggering this failure but it's important to remember that [Firestore rules are not filters](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

If your query is something like this:

```
firestore.collection("conversation").get()
```

And if you're expecting that Firestore will return only the conversations where the rule evaluates to `true` then that is not going to work. Firestore will see that *some* conversation documents would *not* evaluate to `true` and *the entire query will fail*.

You need to ensure the query that you run that causes a rule evaluation is only looking at conversations where the rule will evaluate to true, e.g.:

```
firestore.collection("conversation").where(<some condition>).get()
```

You can read more in the official [Firestore rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are right. I was querying all the conversations. I added the code in the question now. How would I have to change the query for it to work at all? Maybe even only client sided for the beginning?

Comment: I would have to get out pen and paper to draw out your schema and run through your rules to give you advice about how to make your current plan work and unfortunately I don't have time for that. My recommendation? Denormalize your data. You have a `/user` collection and I assume that your rules permit only user A access to `/user/A` and only user B to `/user/B`, therefore you should store a complete copy of the entire conversation under *each user*, e.g., `/user/A/conversation/C` and `/user/B/conversation/C` each hold an entire copy of all the data that each user is permitted to read about it.